# rank users and join tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I rank users based on points and join that user_sno with refno of another table?
I am not getting right ranking with the code below :

```
select *, (@rank := @rank + 1) as rank
from tblB uv 
 join tblC c on uv.sno=c.refno
 join
     (select @rank := 0) const
where uv.sno in (2, 4,5) 
order by rank;
```

I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9be59/12

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sno varchar(255),
name varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblC
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
data varchar(255),
  refno varchar(255),
  points int(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);






INSERT INTO tblB (sno, name ) VALUES
('1', 'Aa'),
('2', 'Bb'),
('3', 'Cc'),
('4', 'Dd'),
('5', 'Ee'),
('6', 'Ff'),
('7', 'Gg'),
('8', 'Hh');


INSERT INTO tblC (data,refno,points ) VALUES
('data1', '1', '101'),
('data2', '2', '102'),
('data3', '3', '103'),
('data4', '4', '101'),
('data5', '5', '102'),
('data6', '6', '103'),
('data7', '7', '101'),
('data8', '8', '101'),
('data9', '9', '101');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `ORDER BY rank`, but you want to `ORDER BY points`, seems like a typo.

Comment: With subselect:

    select ranks.*, (@ rank := @ rank + 1) as rank
    from (
      select uv.id, uv.sno, uv.name, c.data, c.refno, c.points
      from tblB uv 
      join tblC c on uv.sno=c.refno
      where uv.sno in (2, 4,5) 
      order by points desc
    ) as ranks
    join (select @ rank := 0) const

Comment: Yes, delete the space between the @'s and ranks - SO thought I would like to link a user.